# move UITableCell

Tags: iphone

I used codes below to move an UITableCell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {


    NSMyObj *newObj=[myArray objectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]]  ;//myArray is the array to store NSMyObj
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]];
    [myArray insertObject:newObj atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];//

}
```

but it reported:

objc[316]: FREED(id): message retain sent to freed object=0x3d3d330

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to temporarily `-retain` the newObj to avoid it becoming owner-less and deallocated.

```
NSMyObj *newObj = [[myArray objectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]] retain]; // <---
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]];
[myArray insertObject:newObj atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];
[newObj release]; // <---
```